# Why can't I complete the content modification when I modify the unicode table in PDF?

Tags: pdf

When I put <0018> <0044> <0026> <0046> Changed to <0018> <0045> <0026> <0047>,PDF content is not displayed from Hello,PDF. Become Hello PEG. enter image description here

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo <</Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (UCS) /Supplement 0>> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
10 beginbfchar
<0001> <0000>
<0018> <0044>
<0026> <0046>
<002C> <0048>
<0057> <0050>
<011E> <0065>
<016F> <006C>
<017D> <006F>
<0355> <002C>
<0358> <002E>
endbfchar
endcmap CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop end end

changed to

/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo <</Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (UCS) /Supplement 0>> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
10 beginbfchar
<0001> <0000>
<0018> <0045>
<0026> <0047>
<002C> <0048>
<0057> <0050>
<011E> <0065>
<016F> <006C>
<017D> <006F>
<0355> <002C>
<0358> <002E>
endbfchar
endcmap CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop end end
```

I want to change it to Hello PEG.May I ask why there is no change after modification? You don't want to use third-party tools, just parse the PDF text, extract the content between stream and endstream, decode it, then replace it and encode it.

Comment: **ToUnicode** maps are not used for displaying glyphs, they may be used for text extraction (e.g. simple copy&paste) from a PDF. Thus, however you manipulate a **ToUnicode** map, the PDF will look the same.

Answer (score 0):

You asked why altering the Character Mapping tables cannot alter the page contents, and in comments it was explained that is not where the graphics are declared on the page. So perhaps it is worth looking at what does happen there too.

Taking your attempt to shift PDF to PEG by adding a bit to each of the second and third characters, on the face of it seems logical. However you are dealing with CIDs and thus, it's not that simple, as generally those characters may not even exist.

Here is an illustration we see the `D` has been imbedded as numeric bytes <0018> but if we use one bit more <0019> it draws a blank not `E`:

[image]

Basically we can only use those inked shapes that were included in the font embedding.

[image]

Comment: After my analysis, it was found that the shape of the character G is not defined in the font style. How can I add a font style to display it normally?